# Strange exercise to show that $S_n/n\to 0$ in probability.

Tags: probability

Suppose $\mathbb E[X_n]=0$ and $\mathbb E[X_nX_m]\leq r(m-n)$ where $m\geq n$ and $r(k)\to 0 $ when $k\to \infty $. Show that $S_n/n\to 0$ in probability where $S_n=X_1+...+X_n$.

**My teacher correction**

If we can show that $\mathbb E[(S_n/n)^2]\to 0$, then we'll have the result.

$$0\leq \mathbb E[(S_n/n)^2]=\frac{1}{n^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb E[X_i^2]+2\sum_{i<j}\mathbb E[X_iX_j]\right)=\frac{1}{n^2}\left(nr(0)+2\sum_{i<j}r(j-i)\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{n^2}\left(nr(0)+2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (n-k)r(k)\right)\leq \frac{2}{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(n-k)r(k).$$
Since $\lim_{k\to \infty }r(k)=0$, we get that $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\mathbb E\left(\frac{S_n}{n}\right)\leq \varepsilon$$
for all $\varepsilon>0$, what prove the claim.

**My way**

My way looks to simple (since my teacher way is more complicate), but I don't understand why is it wrong. We have that $$\mathbb E[|S_n/n|]=0$$
since $\mathbb E[X_n]$ for all $n$, and thus, by Markov inequality,
$$\mathbb P\{|S_n/n|\}\leq \frac{\mathbb E[S_n/n]}{\varepsilon}=0,$$
and thus it converge in probability.

**Question : What can be wrong here ?**

Comment: [Markov inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) applies to **nonnegative** random variable.

Comment: @drhab: But don't we have that $|S_n/n|$ is non negative ?

Comment: Then why not $\mathbb E(|S_n|/n)$?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[|S_n/n|] = 0$ would imply that $S_n = 0$ almost surely, which is clearly not the case; take $X_n$ to be uniformly distributed on $[-1, 1]$, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only know $\Bbb {E}(S_n /n)=0$, not $\Bbb {E}(|S_n /n |)=0$.